# SQL: Select the latest datetime value when duplicates found on another column

Tags: sql, datetime, select, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have a table called `service_reports`. The table has four columns:

1. `id` column
2. Foreign key column `fk_service` referring to a service that the
   report is about
3. a datetime column `done_date` which represents the point in time
   when the report was finalized.
4. Lastly, it has a boolean (BIT) column `isFinalReport`.

Now, some services have multiple service reports about them and I want to select all but the newest report of each group that refers to a certain service. I want to set the `isFinalReport` boolean value in all but the latest report referring to the same service, as false. Thereby leaving the latest `service_report` as the final report.

Example: `service_reports` rows(`id`) 10 11 and 12 all refer to `fk_service` 25, so there are three rows in the `service_reports` table that refer to that same `fk_service`.

Now, let's say row 12 is the latest of these three reports. I want to set the `isFinalReport` as false in `service_reports` 10 and 11.

I need to do this to all entries in the table, where more than one `service_report` refers to same `fk_service`

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would actually do this in a trigger where when a new row is added it sets the isFinalReport to false for its older siblings.

But this is how I would answer your question:

```
update a
set a.isFinalReport = false
from service_reports a
where isnull(a.isFinalReport, 1) = 1
and exists
(select 1
from service_reports b
where b.fk_service = a.fk_service
and b.done_date > a.done_date)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was sort of in the right direction but this is like 50% the size of the query I was working with. This certainly is more elegant and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @service_reports TABLE
(
 id            INT PRIMARY KEY,
 fk_service    INT,
 done_date     DATETIME,
 isFinalReport BIT
)

INSERT INTO @service_reports
(
   id           
  ,fk_service   
  ,done_date    
  ,isFinalReport
)
VALUES
(
  10
 ,25
 ,'2015-04-14'
 ,1
)

INSERT INTO @service_reports
(
   id           
  ,fk_service   
  ,done_date    
  ,isFinalReport
)
VALUES
(
  11
 ,25
 ,'2015-04-15'
 ,1
)

INSERT INTO @service_reports
(
   id           
  ,fk_service   
  ,done_date    
  ,isFinalReport
)
VALUES
(
  12
 ,25
 ,'2015-04-16'
 ,1
)

UPDATE sr
   SET sr.isFinalReport = 0
  FROM @service_reports sr
  JOIN 
     (
       SELECT id,    
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_service  ORDER BY done_date DESC) AS rowNumber
         FROM @service_reports
     ) s
    ON s.id = sr.id
 WHERE s.rowNumber > 1


SELECT *
  FROM @service_reports
```